# Cordova barcode scanner not working on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm having some issues setting up the BarcodeScanner on Ionic 3.19. This is my code so far. Test device is a LG Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1. I'm running Cordova 7.0.1.

The following implementation works as expected in the browser, but on the phone, it simply tells me that "Permission is granted" and then the camera for the barcode scanner does not come up.

**deposit-money.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner, BarcodeScannerOptions } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { AndroidPermissions  } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions';

import { ScanQRCodeModal } from '../scan-qr-code/scan-qr-code';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-deposit',
  templateUrl: 'deposit-money.html'
})
export class DepositMoneyPage {

  options: BarcodeScannerOptions;
  scanData: {};

  constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, 
              private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions,
              private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  checkCameraPermissions() {
    this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
      success => { alert('Permission granted'); this.scanQRCode()},
      err => { alert('asking for permisison'); this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA) }
    );
  }

  scanQRCode() {
    this.options = {
      prompt : "Scan your voucher code"
    }
    this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then((barcodeData) => {
      console.log(barcodeData);
      this.scanData = barcodeData;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Error occured: " + err);
    }); 
  }

  showScanQRCodeModal() {
    let scanQRCodeModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ScanQRCodeModal);
    scanQRCodeModal.present();   
  }
}
```

**deposit-money.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Deposit Money
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item (click)="checkCameraPermissions()">Scan QR Code</button>
    </ion-list>

    <div *ngIf="scanData">
        <p>Scanned Text:  {{scanData.text}}</p>
        <p>Scanned Format: {{scanData.format}}</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this plugin

```
<plugin spec="https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner.git" source="git" >
    <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To scan barcodes." />
    </plugin>
```